# Migrate Wasabi Wallet to BlueWallet

Tags: private-key-export, wallet-import, wasabi-wallet, bluewallet

I am looking to use an transfer an existing Wasabi Wallet to BlueWallet.

I tried using the extended private key but no luck.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is this even possible?**

Yes.

---

### In General

You can move wallet contents from almost any Bitcoin wallet software to any other Bitcoin wallet software that supports the same standards. For example, if the first wallet supports Bech32, you will need the second wallet to also support Bech32.

There are only a couple of small pieces of data that need to be copied into the new wallet and exactly how you do this depends on the specific wallet software used. We should remember that *just because something is possible doesn't always mean it is easy*.

The general process is to transfer the **private keys**. In the case of HD wallets, you can effectively do this by one of several methods, including:

- Using a seed-phrase (also known as recovery-phrase or backup-phrase) that conforms to a known standard (BIP39, Electrum, etc).
- Using the master private key, typically in wallet import format (WIF)

You also need to specify the **derivation path** as this determines which  Bitcoin addresses had been created by the first wallet from the master private key.

---

### Specifics

If we look at the specific wallet you mentioned, [Blue wallet](https://bluewallet.io/bitcoin-wallet/) allows you to import wallet contents from a variety of other software and allows you to specify a key in WIF format.

To extract a master private key from Wasabi you may need to resort to tools like https://github.com/lontivero/ExtractXPrivWasabi (untested, no idea if it is safe, best to inspect source, build from source, run on computer without ethernet or WiFi  etc, isolated from any network)

Comment: Much Appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need a bip39 seed. Probably a WIF will also work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Bitcoin Stackexchange. Thanks for stepping up to answer this question. On this site, we're looking to build a comprehensive body of questions and answers about all things Bitcoin. To make your answers more helpful to future readers, please add a bit more explanation.